# dropping a MySQL table in a method complying to the Department of Defense Data Clearing and Sanitizing Standard

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I need to delete a set of MySQL *tables* for a client in a manner that's compliant with the Department of Defense Data Clearing and Sanitizing Standard. I've a list of acceptable tools including [wipe](http://wipe.sourceforge.net/), but I'm not clear on how I might be able to drop a MySQL table in such a manner.

Is there a way to tell MySQL to drop the table without deleting the physical files on disk, so I can securely overwrite them manually?

Comment: _Which_ standard?

Comment: @MichaelHampton The link provided to me goes to a 404. I do know that they require a three-pass overwrite, and it mentions 5220.22-M.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is any way to securely delete a table in MySQL, or to delete it without removing the file.

There are a few options I can think of though:

- Export the database into a new one (without the tables you want to delete), switch whatever accesses the database to use the new one, then wipe the old one
- Delete the table, then wipe the free space on the drive
- Stop MySQL, wipe the files for the table you want to delete, restart mysql, check/repair the database

Disclaimer:  I have not tested any of these methods - use at your own risk and make sure your backups are good.